# Order By SQL Query based on Value another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this:

[image: Current Table]

And I want to short the data based on ParentID that refer to ID. So, if the data with ParentID 5 it will be under the data with ID 5. So this is the expected data that I want:

[image: Expected Table]

Is it possible to do that? If its possible, how to order that data?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common table expression (CTE) to first query the parent records, and then query the children records in the second query.  If you create a `sort` column, you can then order the data perfectly:

```
create table #temp (
  id int,
  name varchar(10),
  [date] date,
  parentid int
)

insert into #temp values
(1, 'AAA', '9/7/2020', 1),
(2, 'BBB', '9/8/2020', 2),
(3, 'CCC', '9/8/2020', 3),
(4, 'DDD', '9/8/2020', 4),
(5, 'EEE', '9/8/2020', 2),
(6, 'FFF', '9/8/2020', 1),
(7, 'GGG', '9/8/2020', 5),
(8, 'HHH', '9/8/2020', 3),
(9, 'III', '9/8/2020', 4),
(10, 'JJJ', '9/8/2020', 10)

;with cte (id, parentid, name, [date], sort) as
(
  /* query #1 : pull only parent records */
  select id, parentid, name, [date],
         cast(right('0000' + cast(row_number() over (order by id) as varchar(5)), 5) as varchar(1024))
  from   #temp
  where  id = parentid                           /* pull just the parent records */

  union all

  /* query #2 : add children records */
  select t.id, t.parentid, t.name, t.[date],
         cast(c.sort + right('0000' + cast(row_number() over (order by t.id) as varchar(5)), 5) as varchar(1024))
  from   cte c                                   /* include data from 1st query */
         inner join #temp t on c.id = t.parentid /* only pull children of the parent records returned in query #1 */
  where  t.id <> t.parentid                      /* a record cannot be a child of itself, prevents infinite recursion */
)
select *
from   cte
order by sort

drop table #temp
```

Which returns this dataset:

```
id          parentid    name       date       sort
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
1           1           AAA        2020-09-07 00001
6           1           FFF        2020-09-08 0000100001
2           2           BBB        2020-09-08 00002
5           2           EEE        2020-09-08 0000200001
7           5           GGG        2020-09-08 000020000100001
3           3           CCC        2020-09-08 00003
8           3           HHH        2020-09-08 0000300001
4           4           DDD        2020-09-08 00004
9           4           III        2020-09-08 0000400001
10          10          JJJ        2020-09-08 00005
```

The key is the `sort` column, which builds a value that can be sorted alphabetically.  Of course, you can exclude the `sort` column from the final output, but I wanted you to see how it builds the sort data.

The recursive nature of CTE queries means that it will continue to loop and re-run the sub-query until all the children + grandchildren + great-grandchildren, etc., have been pulled.  That is why the `sort` data for the `GGG` record has 3 parts of data.

Comment: Thank you for your help to answer my question. I have tried that query and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using self join like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.Date
FROM TableName t1
INNER JOIN TableName t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ParentId
```

Comment: I have only one table. Do I have to join if I only have one table?

Comment: I have tried that query, but still can not show the expected data that I want. But, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Alex : the query missing the order by... you need to add " order by t2.[parentid],t1.[id]" and remove t2.Date ,  it should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking to sort all of the data hierarchically. This can be best done with [CTE's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

In your case the SQL would look like this:

```
with t as 
(select 1 id, 'aaa' name, cast('20200907' as date) date, 1 parentid union
select 2 id, 'bbb' name,  cast('20200908' as date) date, 2 parentid union
select 3 id, 'ccc' name,  cast('20200909' as date) date, 3 parentid union
select 4 id, 'ddd' name,  cast('20200910' as date) date, 4 parentid union
select 5 id, 'eee' name,  cast('20200911' as date) date, 2 parentid union
select 6 id, 'fff' name,  cast('20200912' as date) date, 1 parentid union
select 7 id, 'ggg' name,  cast('20200913' as date) date, 5 parentid union
select 8 id, 'hhh' name,  cast('20200914' as date) date, 3 parentid union
select 9 id, 'iii' name,  cast('20200915' as date) date, 4 parentid union
select 10 id, 'jjj' name, cast('20200916' as date) date, 10 parentid)

, t1 (id, name, date, parentid, level) as (
select id, name, date, parentid, 0 from t where id = parentid  --starting condition (top level, no higher ancestors)
union all
select t.id, t.name, t.date, t.parentid, t1.level + 1 --level goes down
from t join t1 on t.parentid = t1.id --hierarchy condition, add those elements that have a direct ancestor already selected
and t.id != t1.parentid --cannot reselect them, otherwise the recursion won't stop
)

select * from t1 order by level, id
```

The end result looks like this
[image: showing the hierarchy and levels of the parentid-id relations]

Answer (score 0):

On a simple dataset that is a hierarchy with a finite number of levels that is small, you can do this by simply self joining.

> You could use this method instead of a `CTE` if your database engine does not support `CTE`s or if you needed to keep the query maintenance simple.

*Setup using table variable*

```
DECLARE @table table (
  id int,
  name varchar(10),
  [date] date,
  parentid int
)

insert into @table values
(1, 'AAA', '9/7/2020', 1),
(2, 'BBB', '9/8/2020', 2),
(3, 'CCC', '9/8/2020', 3),
(4, 'DDD', '9/8/2020', 4),
(5, 'EEE', '9/8/2020', 2),
(6, 'FFF', '9/8/2020', 1),
(7, 'GGG', '9/8/2020', 5),
(8, 'HHH', '9/8/2020', 3),
(9, 'III', '9/8/2020', 4),
(10, 'JJJ', '9/8/2020', 10)
```

*Query from the `@table` with 3 levels of depth*

```
SELECT child.id, child.name, child.[date], child.parentId
FROM @table child
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table parent on child.parentid = parent.id
ORDER BY parent.parentid, child.parentid, child.id
```

If your data structure has nulls to indicate that there is no parent, then this query can be more efficient again, but we have to `COALESCE` the Ids:

```
SELECT child.id, child.name, child.[date], child.parentId
FROM @table child
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table parent on child.parentid = parent.id
order by COALESCE(parent.parentid,child.parentid,child.Id), IsNull(child.parentid,child.Id), child.id
```

Finally, to support each additional level of recursion, add another *join*, ultimately you will need `n-2` joins where `n` is the maximum number of levels your data will support, the following supports 4 levels:

```
SELECT child.id, child.name, child.[date], child.parentId
FROM @table child
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table parent on child.parentid = parent.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table grandparent on parent.parentid = grandparent.id
order by COALESCE(grandparent.parentId, parent.parentid,child.parentid,child.Id), COALESCE(parent.parentid,child.parentid,child.Id), IsNull(child.parentid,child.Id), child.id
```